# Probability of $A \cup B'$

Tags: probability

$P(A)= 0.25$
$P(B)=0.4$
 
$P(A \cup B)=0.5$

Find
 
$P(A \cup B')$
$P(A' \cup B)$
$P(A \cap B')$
$P(A' \cap B)$

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Also, when you post a question here, it is expected that you share your own thoughts on the problem.  You should indicate what you have tried and where you are stuck so that you receive responses appropriate to your skill level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following facts:

$$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$$
$$P(A')=1-P(A)$$
$$P(A\cap B')=P(A)-P(A\cap B)$$

Comment: Why is the downvote?

Answer (score 1):

Draw out a Venn diagram and label every component appropriately. Add and substract as necessary to get your answer.

I do not believe any more explicit answer will help you understand this problem. I strongly recommend this visual approach.